# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler<object>' for storyboard complete

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have read already a few threads about this, but I still don't know how to solve it in my case. I come from Java and mostly new to C#

I want to attach listener when animation finishes:

```
myStoryBoard.Completed += new EventHandler(onMyStoryBoardCompleted);
```

And:

```
private void onMyStoryBoardCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
}
```

And I get the error in the title. I tried:

```
 myStoryBoard.Completed += new EventHandler<object>(onMyStoryBoardCompleted);
```

But then I get:

```
no overload for 'onMyStoryBoardCompleted' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler<object>'
```

So it seems that the signature is not compatible with EventHandler`<object>` and I couldn't find how to make it compatible, I also don't know if this approach is correct.

I read

[Understanding events and event handlers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp)

[C# Dynamic template implicit conversion error from System.EventHandler to System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073965/c-sharp-dynamic-template-implicit-conversion-error-from-system-eventhandler-to-s)

[defining event handler for Tick event of DispatcherTimer in windows 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464374/defining-event-handler-for-tick-event-of-dispatchertimer-in-windows-8-app)

But still don't find the solution for this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `myStoryBoard.Completed += new EventHandler(onMyStoryBoardCompleted);` should work

Comment: Which StoryBoard class are you using? If it's `Timeline` derived, the `Completed` should be defined as type EventHandler, which means this should compile without error.

Comment: I'm referencing a storyboard from XAML in UserControl.Resource tag

Comment: @SLaks: Not on Windows 8 Metro. Apparently, it really is `EventHandler<object>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
private void onMyStoryBoardCompleted(object sender, object e)
{ }
```

And subscribe using the generic `EventHandler<object>`:

```
myStoryBoard.Completed += new EventHandler<object>(onMyStoryBoardCompleted);
```

Of course, this goes against the .NET Framework convention that the second argument to an event handler should be an instance of `EventArgs` (or a class derived thereof). I am assuming that you are running on another framework, such as Windows 8 Metro, whose `Timeline` class defines a [`Completed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.completed) event with an `EventHandler<object>` signature.

Comment: Did you try it using the generic `EventHandler<object>`? What error did you get?

Comment: Ah, that combination actually works! It's strange since the method signature was generated by Visual Studio. And yes, I'm developing for Metro.

Comment: Or well, not strange, Visual Studio did it correctly, since it generated it for EventHandler(onMyStoryBoardCompleted).

Comment: I was surprised too that Microsoft themselves would break the `EventArgs` convention. (I'm not particularly familiar with Metro.)

Comment: @Murkaeus please don't add unnecessary comments, I think my profile doesn't look like I don't know how to use SO.

Comment: @Ixx all the more bewildering that you haven't marked the answer as correct

Comment: @Murkaeus Is there a time limit or something to mark answers as correct? The fact that I added a comment saying "it works", doesn't mean necessarily that everything is fine, maybe I want to double check it (runtime, etc.). Maybe I have something else to do before that. Don't know how long you have been using this site, but FYI answer selection offen takes hours, days, or weeks.