# Cannot implicitly convert type System.EventHandler to System.EventHandler<object> error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to implement a Timer in windows phone app.It works fine in Windows Phone App(Silverlight) but it isnt working in Windows Phone Blank App.But it gives me following error-

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.EventHandler to System.EventHandler<object>
```

This is my code -

```
namespace Timer
{
    public partial class MainPage : Page
    {           
        DispatcherTimer mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int currentcount = 0;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mytimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            mytimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
            mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mytime_Tick);
              //HERE error comes Cannot implicitly convert type System.EventHandler to System.EventHandler<object>
        }

        private void mytime_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            timedisplayBlock.Text = currentcount++.ToString();    
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mytimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler<object>' for storyboard complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636830/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-eventhandler-to-system-eventhandlerobj/16636862#16636862)

But it even helped.How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Referencing the method handler for the event directly will infer the type, satisfying the generic type declaration requirement.

```
mytimer.Tick += mytime_Tick;
```

Alternatively, explicitly declaring the generic type and using the generic EventHandler constructor,

```
mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(mytime_Tick);
```

would do the trick.

In addition, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.tick), your handler has the wrong signature.  It should be:

```
private void mytime_Tick(object sender,object e)
{
    timedisplayBlock.Text = currentcount++.ToString();    
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just write  `mytimer.Tick +=` then press **TAB Key** two times it will fix your bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid a conversion, you can always do the following:

```
mytimer.Tick += (s, ev) => { mytime_Tick(s, ev); }
```

It's very useful if you are validating nullables:

```
mytimer.Tick += (s, ev) => { mytime_Tick?.Invoke(s, ev); }
```

Regards, Nicholls

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is trying to tell you, you need to create an `EventHandler<object>`.

Or, better yet, leave the delegate type out entirely and just add the method name.

Comment: Both of this is giving me this same new error- No overload for mytime_Tick` matches delegate `System.EventHandler<object>