# Why can't I add a handler to PropertyChanged with EventHandler attribute type (by reference to method)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm doing something like this:

```
void komar_EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do somethig
}

...
{
    Komar k = new Komar();

    k.PropertyChanged += komar_EventHandler; // OK (why?)


    EventHandler methodRef = komar_EventHandler;

    k.PropertyChanged += methodRef;                              // Error !
    k.PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)methodRef; // Error !


    // I know solution, but I don't like it :)
    k.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { methodRef(s, e); };

}
```

Why can I add a handler with different type immediately, but I can't use reference to a method?

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654057.aspx).

Comment: What is the error and what did your research show? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522523/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-eventhandler-to-system-eventhandlerobject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> k.PropertyChanged += komar_EventHandler; // OK (why?)
> ```

Because the compiler automatically converts the method group `komar_EventHandler` to a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` delegate. It's the same as if your code was:

```
k.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(komar_EventHandler);
```

> ```
> k.PropertyChanged += methodRef;                              // Error !
> ```

The `PropertyChanged` event expects a `PropertyChangedEventHandler`, not an `EventHandler`. There's no implicit conversion between different delegate types.

> ```
> k.PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)methodRef; // Error !
> ```

An `EventHandler` can't be cast to a `PropertyChangedEventHandler`; it's just not a valid conversion. You can, however, create a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` from a `EventHandler`:

```
k.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(methodRef);
```

Comment: Nice answer however i'd comment the solution that OP doesn't like as well (with lambda)

Answer (score 1):

[Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39613762/2122718) you've got a point. I forgot about this:

```
k.PropertyChanged += komar_EventHandler; // OK (why?)
// because:
k.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(komar_EventHandler);
```

But the solution my question is, however, other.

**Compiler need a method, so the solution is:**

```
k.PropertyChanged += methodRef.Invoke;                               // OK !
k.PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)methodRef.Invoke;  // OK !
```

Edit:
We can do it also this way:

```
k.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(methodRef);
// Debugger showed me that k.PropertyChanged has reference
// to the method methodRef.Invoke same as k.PropertyChanged += methodRef.Invoke;
```

Comment: Yes, `methodRef.Invoke` works too, since it's a method with a compatible signature

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Oh, I just saw that you have completed your answer before I wrote mine. So... you should win :)