# Unable to convert Eventhandler to KeyPressEventHandler

Tags: c#

Whilst running the below code, I get this exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert System.Eventhandler to
>   System.Window.Form.KeyPressEventHandler

```
    private void grdPOItems_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        int colIndex = grdPOItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        string colName = grdPOItems.Columns[colIndex].Name;
        if(colName == "Qty" || colName == "Rate")
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress += new EventHandler(CheckKey);
        }
    }

    private void CheckKey(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 57) && e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar!='.'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }  
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler<object>' for storyboard complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636830/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-eventhandler-to-system-eventhandlerobj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`MSDN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx), your handler has the wrong signature. Use this instead.

```
 e.Control.KeyPress += CheckKey;

private void CheckKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs  e)
{
    if (((e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 57) && e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar!='.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }  
}
```